# any Cordova alternatives to the iOS UI ImagePicker

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm using the Cordova camera API to pick photos from the PhotoLibrary/CameraRoll, and it generally works fine. However, the native iOS ImagePicker only offers square thumbnails that are too small and basically useless for albums with a large number (1000+) of photos. It is  especially annoying when you picked the wrong version of 2 photos that are 10+ swipes from the top. And this is especially true with the pop-up on an iPad that offers so much screen space.

Does anyone know of an alternative that would give me the ability to configure thumbnail size, or even offer previews? Multi-select would also be useful. Is there anything available to the HTML5/Cordova-plugin world? Or can this only be done with native iOS code?

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the asset library yourself, you can use aspectRatioThumbnail

```
ALAsset * ass = (ALAsset *)image;
CGImageRef ref = [ass aspectRatioThumbnail];
```